# Read into Dask from Minio raises issue with reading / converting binary string JSON into utf8

Tags: dask, minio

I'm trying to read JSON-LD into Dask from Minio.   The pipeline works but the strings come from Minio as binary strings

So

```py
with oss.open('gleaner/summoned/repo/file.jsonld', 'rb') as f:
  print(f.read())
```

results in

```
b'\n{\n    "@context": "http://schema.org/",\n    "@type": "Dataset",\n  ...
```

I can simply convert this with

```py
with oss.open('gleaner/summoned/repo/file.jsonld', 'rb') as f:
   print(f.read().decode("utf-8"))
```

and now everything is as I expect it.

However, I am working with Dask and when reading into the a bag with

```py
dgraphs = db.read_text('s3://bucket/prefa/prefb/*.jsonld', 
      storage_options={
          "key": key,
          "secret": secret,
          "client_kwargs": {"endpoint_url":"https://example.org"}
          }).map(json.loads)
```

I can not get the content coming from Minio to become strings vs binary strings.  I need these converted before they hit the json.loads map I suspect.

I assume I can inject the "decode" in here somehow as well, but I can't resolve how.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the name implies, `read_text` opens the remote file in text mode, equivalent to `open(..., 'rt')`. The [signature](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/bag-api.html#dask.bag.read_text) of `read_text` includes the various decoding arguments, such as UTF8 as the default encoding. You should not need to do anything else, but please post a specific error if you are having trouble, ideally with example file contents.

If your data isn't delimited by lines, read_text might not be right for you, and you can do something like

```
@dask.delayed()
def read_a_file(fn):
    # or preferably open in text mode and json.load from the file
    with oss.open('gleaner/summoned/repo/file.jsonld', 'rb') as f:
        return json.loads(f.read().decode("utf-8"))

output = [read_a_file(f) for f in filenames]
```

and then you can create a bag or dataframe from this, as required.

Comment: thanks for the help on this follow up question too.   I will try and see if I can provide more details but it's a bit hard as all my Minio buckets require key and secret.   

If read text can accept UTF decode argument I just need to resolve how to put it in.

The example file is at http://oss.openknowledge.network/test/test.jsonld?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE%2F20200721%2F%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200721T032245Z&X-Amz-Expires=604800&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=4c56a2aa6896a5e83346d7ac5c2031bde95015a6a942206cfff7ad145df48917

Comment: One issue I see..    do the JSON files need to be a single line?   If so then that could be the issue.

I tried

`dgraphs = db.read_text('s3://gleaner/summoned/opentopo/*.jsonld', 
      storage_options={
          "key": key,
          "secret": secret,
          "client_kwargs": {"endpoint_url":"https://oss.geodex.org"}
          }).str.replace('\n','').map(json.loads)`

the str.replace to see if I could remove new lines, but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: I put up a ipynb I am using at https://gist.github.com/fils/a75d1995644bf156a8624d039f6064dc   It can read a public bucket on a test minio server.      I am wondering if this has to do with new lines in the JSON-LD documents?

Comment: Yes, read_text views a file as a sequence of lines. If your JSON spans lines, you will need a custom function with dask.delayed; example coming.

Comment: Thanks once again..   I got everything working with your guidance and back into my JSON-LD workflow where I am much more comfortable.   Very interested to see about leveraging Dask more for processing large numbers of JSON-LD documents.  Take care!